# Manipular window.history do JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de listar as URL's do `window.history`? Se eu quero usar `window.history.go(-2)`, tem como saber qual URL esse -2 vai retornar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Isso não é possível.

Há questões de segurança envolvido pelo fato de que todo site que você visita\visitou poderia ser visto por todos os outros sites que você esteve.

Uma alterativa para contornar isso, desde que esteja em seu próprio site seria usar técnicas de gerenciamento de sessão, são eles:

- *Dados de Cookies*
- *Parâmetros de URL*
- *Informações de Sessão do lado do servidor*

Answer (score 3):

Com navegações normais não, no entanto é possível "criar/manipular" as URLs usando, a navegação neste caso seria por ajax:

```
var estadoDoObj = { foo: "bar" }; //Estado "atual"

history.pushState(estadoDoObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

e poderia combinar com `sessionStorage` e usar algo com `var currentState = history.state;` para obter o estado.

E para detectar as mudanças use este evento:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
  //...
});
```

> Não encontrei nada pronto, nem no Github, mas vou continuar procurando, se não conseguir nada tentarei criar um exemplo funcional básico (claro que a aplicação disto vai depender muito de como é o seu sistema)